# Kubernetes: How to find installed storage provisioners

Tags: kubernetes, storage

With Kubernetes on can define storage classes with provisioners. How does one find which provisioners are installed and available in the cluster?

Inspecting the storage classes will reveal which provisioners are already in use, but not whether there are more available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A provisioner does not necessarily need to run in the cluster, e.g. the provisioner for an external storage appliance just connects to the cluster api server and watches for new persistent volume requests created with a storage class bound to its provisioner name. This is why as of Kubernetes 1.7 there is no intended universal way to see if a storage classes provisioner is actually available or not.

Comment: When you specify in a storage class a provisioner that does not exist, and then try to create a persistent volume claim with this class you get the following error: "no volume plugin matched". How kubernets knows that no volume plugin matched if it does not have the list?

Comment: see this answer for a more in depth explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/75205919