# How does the Kubernetes API know what Pod to use given the provisioner field in a StorageClass?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm currently trying to understand the underlying logic of how an external storage provisioner works in Kubernetes.

I have Minikube installed, and can see that the standard StorageClass resource has the field `provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath`.
I am also aware of the Pod running this provisioner controller, `storage-provisioner`, which runs on the *kube-system* namespace. I know that when a PVC requests some storage from the StorageClass, it uses the `storage-provisioner` Pod to create and supply this storage.

What I want to know is *how* the Kubernetes API knows this is correct Pod to use given the provisioner field in the StorageClass.

What I know so far is that the StorageClass has the label `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=EnsureExists` and the `storage-provisioner` Pod has the label `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile`. These are different, so the Kubernetes API can't be using these as selectors to map them.

I had a look at all the other API resources using these labels and found the following with `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=EnsureExists`:

- `rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:persistent-volume-provisioner`
- `role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:persistent-volume-provisioner`

I then found the following with `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile`:

- `endpoints/k8s.io-minikube-hostpath`
- `serviceaccount/storage-provisioner`

I used `kubectl describe` on the Roles resource and noticed it has a PolicyRule for the `endpoints/k8s.io-minikube-hostpath`. I did the same for the Rolebinding resource and noticed it has `serviceaccount/storage-provisioner` under Subjects.

My assumption is that this associates `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=EnsureExists` with `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile`, which associates the `provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath` field with the `storage-provisioner`, thereby allowing the Kubernetes API to identify the correct Pod to use.

I'm not that well-versed in the inner-workings of the Kubernetes API, so I have a feeling I am wrong. If so how does this work?

Thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was looking at this all wrong.
What actually happens is the `storage-provisioner` Pod itself is the controller, and this controller watches for any PVC requests to any StorageClass that has the `provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath` field; provisioning volumes respectively.

This can all be seen in the actual code implementation of the controller at https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/pkg/storage/storage_provisioner.go

First at line 37 we have `const provisionerName = "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath"`

Then at line 139 we have `pc := controller.NewProvisionController(clientset, provisionerName, hostPathProvisioner, serverVersion.GitVersion)` which creates the Controller.

I looked further within the source code of this function at https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-lib-external-provisioner/blob/52106c755f34bc764626e2e75f08352d9c3edce5/controller/controller.go

The controller's control loops start at line 809, `func (ctrl *ProvisionController) Run(ctx context.Context) {`

Then it calls `runClaimWorker()` at line 856. I just followed the bouncing ball from here until it eventually creates the provision by calling the Provision function on line 1426, `volume, result, err := ctrl.provisioner.Provision(ctx, options)`

This function exists at line 64 here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-lib-external-provisioner/blob/52106c755f34bc764626e2e75f08352d9c3edce5/examples/hostpath-provisioner/hostpath-provisioner.go#L64

Quite interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Actually Kubernetes API Server keeps record of all Kubernetes Objects.
Kubernetes objects are identified by their kind,name and namespace triplet(unique identifier).
A Kubernetes object is a "record of intent"--once you create the object, the Kubernetes system will constantly work to ensure that object exists.

Official docs
[Kubernetes Objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/)